# wrapping text of a UITextView (line break mode)

Tags: ios, uitextview, uicollectionview

A UITextView (kind of modal : it is shown when pressing on a button) appears for the user to collect what he wants to write in another UITextView which is fixed.
I resize the UITextView's height (the one which is fixed), and put in it the text that has been entered by the user in the other (modal) UITextView. 
But, instead of doing the line break (as it did in the modal UITextView), the fixed UITextView does not wrap the text... 
How can I make the fixed UITextView wrap the text ?

Here is my code :

```
textsToDisplay[index] = [enterText text];

    NSInteger _stringTotalLength=[[enterText text] length];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attSt=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[enterText text]];
    [attSt addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                  value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringTotalLength)];

    float height3 = ceil(attSt.size.height);

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)){
        cellSizes[index] = CGSizeMake(screenWidth-6,height3+10);
    }else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)){
        cellSizes[index] = CGSizeMake(screenHeight-25,height3+10);
    }
```

I store the text which was entered by the user in textsToDisplay which is a table of NSString. I am using a UICollectionView whose cells contain the fixed UITextView and I set the text in the following method :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableAttributedString *attSt=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textsToDisplay[index]];
    NSInteger _stringTotalLength=[textsToDisplay[index] length];
    [attSt addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                  value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringTotalLength)];
    cell.textView.attributedText =attSt;
```

I create the uitextview for entering code like this :

```
float width = 500.0f;

    enterText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-(width)/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2-200, width, 400)];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attSt=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:questionCell.textView.text];
    NSInteger _stringTotalLength=[questionCell.textView.text length];
    [attSt addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                  value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringTotalLength)];
    enterText.attributedText = attSt;
    enterText.tag = 92;
    enterText.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    enterText.alpha = 1;
    enterText.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:enterText];
```

and here is how I create the uitextview in a cell :

```
 textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, widthLabel-50, 50)];
        textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and I configure it like this :

```
cell.textView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, cellSizes[index].width-50, cellSizes[index].height);
```

Comment: Wrapping is control by properties of UITextView. Can you check how two of them configured? Are you creating them from NIB or in the code?

Comment: I edited my question to let you see how I create it programatically

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a uilabel in each uicollectionviewcell because it is way too complex to do the line break with a uitextview.